# How to get frequency of a pattern

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have documents like below. What I want is to get frequency of apple words(1 apple_x, 2 apple_y, 1 apple_z). What is the best way for doing this. I get data from logstash by the way. Should I use add_field filter in logstash?

```
{
    "field1": "text text apple_x text text"
}

{
    "field1": "text text apple_y text text"
}

{
    "field1": "text text apple_y text text"
}

{
    "field1": "text text apple_z text text"
}
```

Comment: "Get the frequency" where?  If you want to use it in your logstash config, that's entirely different than running an ES query or showing something in Kibana.

Comment: The [Logstash Node Stats API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.0/node-stats-api.html#pipeline-stats) may give you what you're looking for. Specifically the pipeline API, which will tell you number of documents that matched or failed to match a specific Logstash input/filter/output.